# Set interparagraph spacing to line spacing

Tags: spacing, formatting, parskip

I have an assignment which the instructor is requiring to have no extra spacing between lines and double spaced. I currently have `\linespread{2}` to get the double spacing but I'm unsure how to go about removing the extra interparagraph spacing. My thoughts on this is to set `\parskip` to be equal to some parameter for line spacing, but I don't know how I would access that. A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is me using this for school make it any different? I'm just trying to learn like everyone else.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should probably add a compilable example of code. It should help to answer the question since the solution might be different according to the document class and the packages used.

Comment: Instead of \linespread` I suggest you to use package `setspace`. Its use is shortly desdcribed in https://www1.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/General/doublespc/`

Comment: Your code make exactly what you want. By default the `\parskip` is 0pt. What else?

Comment: With your code there can be *no* extra space between paragraph, because `article` uses `\raggedbottom`. Hence the flexibility of the default value for `\parskip` is never exploited. If you get different spacing between paragraphs, there must be something else you aren't showing.

Comment: That makes sense. There were a few paragraphs that looked like they had extra space, but I guess it was just my eyes tricking me.